# Bootstrap collapse change icon

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Can someone help me to fix little bug. I use bootstrap 4 alpha 6. Below you can see picture.
[image]
As you see I have several collapse blocks in my page. One of this collapse block inside other collapse block. When I click the button to open that internal block (with inside data-toggle) it changes the icon of top data-toggle. Whats wrong I did in my JS?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-header">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-group-task" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-group-task">
              <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="card-block">
      <div class="collapse" id="collapse-group-task">
         <div class="list-group">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-end custom-d-flex">
               <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-group-task-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-group-task-1">
                  <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#9;<span>Comments</span>
               </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse w-100 comment-list-block" id="collapse-group-task-1">
                  ***SOME TEXT***
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.collapse')
        .on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
            $(this)
                .parent().parent()
                .find(".fa-eye")
                .removeClass("fa-eye")
                .addClass("fa-eye-slash");
        })
        .on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
            $(this)
                .parent().parent()
                .find(".fa-eye-slash")
                .removeClass("fa-eye-slash")
                .addClass("fa-eye");
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you have accordion inside accordion, they all have same class collapse, same `event`. A solution is to stop event of `parent element` with `stopPropagation()`.

Here I made a fiddle: [fiddle link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/teutakoraqi/zf858fp6/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your current jQuery will listen to all collapse event on a page, and as you added accordion inside accordion, they all have same event. You could use `stopPropagation()` as mentioned in the other answer, or you could check `event.target` or you could add a unique class to your parent accordion and add event listener using that class, all will solve your problem.

Here is a solution, using `event.target` to only make changes if parent accordion is opened or closed.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.collapse')
        .on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  if(e.target.id !== 'collapse-group-task'){return}
            $(this)
                .parent().parent()
                .find(".fa-eye")
                .removeClass("fa-eye")
                .addClass("fa-eye-slash");
        })
        .on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  if(e.target.id !== 'collapse-group-task'){return}
            $(this)
                .parent().parent()
                .find(".fa-eye-slash")
                .removeClass("fa-eye-slash")
                .addClass("fa-eye");
        });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
</head>
<body>

<section class="container">
 <section class="row">
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-header">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-group-task" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-group-task">
              <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="card-block">
      <div class="collapse" id="collapse-group-task">
         <div class="list-group">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-end custom-d-flex">
               <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-group-task-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-group-task-1">
                  <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#9;<span>Comments</span>
               </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse w-100 comment-list-block" id="collapse-group-task-1">
                  ***SOME TEXT***
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

</div>  
 </section>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Jsbin of the above snippet https://jsbin.com/libege/edit?html,js,output